A question related to Sobolev spaces
Let $\varphi \in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ is open (or even exterior domain, in an extreme case). If $\varphi^+ := \max (0,\varphi) \in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)$ and
$$\int_{\Omega} |\nabla \varphi| \ \mathrm{d}x = 0,$$
where $\nabla \varphi$ is the weak gradient, so does $\varphi^+ = 0$ almost everywhere in $\Omega$?
Note: Maybe this is an easy question, but I have some doubts about the sobolev trace. Any help is welcome!

Did you mean the condition $\int_\Omega |\nabla \phi^+|=0?$
